# php file_put_contents: Permission denied on windows

Tags: php, file-put-contents

I have a folder on my desktop with a `php` file. Everytime I try to execute that `php` file with `file_put_contents` I get `Failed to open stream: Permission denied` which is extremely furstrating. With other languages like `Ruby` or `Python` it works fine. How do I enable `php` to read and write files on my pc anywhere?

Comment: Are you launching the PHP file from the same directory in which it is stored? 
Are you writing the file in the same directory as the PHP file?
How are you specifying the current directory in PHP?
Are you launching PHP from the terminal or from webserver?
What are the permissions of the folder that you're trying to write?

Comment: Had this issue after I updated my windows OS. Try using another directory